# Variable is used before being assigned using hasOwnProperty

Tags: typescript

Here continue my adventures in my transition from JavaScript to TypeScript... Once again it's a code that used to work well but now it's not. I searched for alternatives or other ways to write it but I cannot seem to find them.

Piece of code :

```
 class secondCommand extends Commands {
    async command() {
       let [ result ] = await sql.promise().query(`SELECT * FROM database WHERE pending = "TRUE"`)
       let userId = result.map(x => x.user_id)
       let login = result.map(x => x.login)
       for (var userIdKey in userId) userId.hasOwnProperty(userIdKey)
       for (var loginKey in login) login.hasOwnProperty(loginKey)
       let [ [ result ] ] = await sql.promise().query(`SELECT birth FROM dates WHERE "login" = "${login[loginKey]}" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`)
       let date = getDateDiff(result)
       ///// rest of code
    }
}
```

Has anyone encountered that problem before? And if so how did you resolve this? Thank you very much

Comment: What exactly is the error message? Also, the `hasOwnProperty` checks you're doing are doing nothing, since the result is not being used

Comment: `Variable 'loginKey' is used before being assigned. ts(2454)`

edit: it says it also for `userIdKey` that I am using later on

Comment: login and userId is an array and it doesn't have hasOwnProperty. And you are not doing anything on the two for loops

Comment: i got your problem you are querying with non defined variable loginKey

Comment: You telling that the variable is not defined got me think to declare it before the for loop and it works now!
Please see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
login.forEach((item) => {
       let [ [ result ] ] = await sql.promise().query(`SELECT birth FROM dates WHERE "login" = "${item}" ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1`)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was so simple ... Here is how to fix it

```
    let userIdKey
    let loginKey
    for (userIdKey in userId) userId.hasOwnProperty(userIdKey)
    for (loginKey in login) login.hasOwnProperty(loginKey)
```

Thank you codingwith3dv!

Comment: this will only give the last index in array